# My screen contains large set of identical views should I add them staticlly or dynamically?

Tags: android, performance, listview

I want to design a screen which contains some ten identical components(each component contains textview and imageview).What's the better way to design it?
Should I add them directly to xml or by looping dynamically.

Comment: you can use listview

Answer (score 1):

Since it contains collection of similar data, use recycler view and add views dynamically using adapter.Refer [this to know more about using recycler view](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)
Via recycler view, views can be reused, thus it manages memory.

Comment: thank you, but in the link you gave it is said "Use the RecyclerView widget when you have data collections whose elements change at runtime based on user action or network events.". but, my elements doesnt change during runtime. they are fixed in number and fixed in functionality.

Comment: You can make collection like ArrayList of your data and inflate that via adapter. This will help in views reuse. Also, in case data exceeds in future, it will be managed by updating new data in collection used. Basically it will provide a generic solution with memory management.